# Difference of yarn classic and yarn 3(node_modules) dependency management methods

Tags: yarnpkg, hadoop-yarn, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

I'm using yarn 3 workspace with `nodelinker: node_modules` option.

As far as I know, using `nodelinker: node_modules` manages the library in the same way as yarn classic.
what is the difference between yarn 3 and yarn classic?

I'm wondering if there's an advantage in terms of managing dependencies more strongly.

When I looked at the lock file of yarn classic and yarn 3, I didn't notice much difference.